# c# mvc3 not showing jquery element after deployment

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, deployment

When I am deploying my solution to my hoster a specific jquery element is just not showing up..

Its showing when i run it on my local pc.. but when deployed it just isnt there.. its a jquery element that renders a menu..

any ideas what could be causing this ?

I've uploaded all the references and everything..

```
jQuery.ajax({ type: "POST",
    url: "/Bubble/MyInterests",
    dataType: "json",
    traditional: true,
    success: function (data) {
        $("#coInterestContainer").empty();
        $("#coInterestTemplate").render(data).appendTo("#coInterestContainer");
        $(document).on('click', '.coInterest', function () {
            location.href="/Bubble/View/" + $(this).attr("id") + "?CreateOffer=1";
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Anything to do with jQuery 'Production' vs 'Development' version? Have you tried?

Comment: Yesterday we came across same situation where  $.Ajax was not being called in publish code. Our solution was while deploying in IIS we set our application to 'integrated' mode.

Comment: not sure what u mean by production vs development version Sandeep

ive deployed by copying files directly using ftp client.. what do you mean by setting application to integrated mode - theinsaneone ?

Comment: Just check web console whether there are any error or not

Comment: @Hailot - what is your deployment URL?  I am assuming it has a subdirectory (e.g. instead of localhost:xxxx its is mysite.com/application).  Is this correct?